# How to get cookie on the server side Angular Universal

Tags: javascript, angular, express, cookies

I have an Angular 4 app with server side rendering. On server side I have such code:

```
const res: express.Response = this.injector.get('RESPONSE');
res.cookie('Name', 'Value');
```

So, how in the component can I access this cookies?
I inject Express RESPONSE in my component, but there are no cookies.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object, private injector: Injector) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      let CircularJSON = require('circular-json');
      let res: express.Response = this.injector.get('RESPONSE');
      console.log("RESPONSE = " + CircularJSON.stringify(res));
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is to get cookie on server side, before they will be set in browser.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this ? I' m also stuck with passing cookie from universal response to client

Comment: @dionisis-k I found solution this https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter in /src/app/shared/for-storage/. There is two implementation for brouser and server for getting cookie. In app.module.ts file you should describe providers block like this: 
  {provide: AppStorage, useClass: CookieStorage}
and in app.server.module.ts file this:
   {provide: AppStorage, useClass: UniversalStorage}
And then in component, where you want to use this storage in constructor use @Inject(AppStorage) private appStorage: Storage.

Comment: Oh great solution .Btw I also find a solution  for your example.    Make sure you provide res   ```app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {req, res});
});``` . And `res.cookie( name, value)` works .A note i used injection tokens instead of injector

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to use this [ngx-cookie-service library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) to have access to cookies?